Windows won't show up on the grub after I dual boot with kali
When I installed the kali linux with dual boot, the windows dual boot wont show on the grub. It was just an Run kali linux and Advance options. I tried already many possible solutions in the internet but I have no luck to solve. My windows storage also showing on the files in linux

Need details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Did you run sudo update-grub and is Windows fast start up or hibernation off?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The Windows "Fast Boot" setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on.

I tried to change the "load default os" in bios and I chose the win84 and after that, it boot into windows. Then I go to bios again and changed the boot priority into legacy mode and change back the load default os into other os. After that, it boot into linux again and I am glad that my dual boot didn't go wrong. Is there anyway to choose the dual boot in grub? Instead of going bios and change some options?
